# Which combination of single chainring and crankset goes with 6 speed?

Tags: crankset, chainring

I have 90s Bianchi "Project 2" which is early hybrid of MTB and roadbike it says. I want to customised to single chainring narrow wide (somewhere between 48 to 40T), but leaving original rear 6 speed (14-28T). I like this old 6 speeds since I don't ride so much on hills.

First question is, is this set up make sense? Does keeping 6speed makes more complication for further set up? Such as finding apprortiate chain, crankset, other parts, etc. If easier or eventually cheaper to install other setup, please let me know.

If keeping 6 speed is possible. I would like to know; which chainring (narrow wide between 48T-40T) and crankset goes well together?
I have a BB-CS11 but I can also replace with other.

I am beginner and stepped into a mud of bike tuning :)

thanks!

Comment: Uff, another of those questions. _Why_? If you have a 2× or 3× system but hardly use the low gears on front – great, so don't use them then. But why would you _remove_ that capability? Weight savings are marginal, narrow-wide is unnecessary with the front derailleur acting as a fixed chain-device (unless you're riding really rough terrain fast), and the real advantage of 1× – more _design freedom_ for the bicycle – doesn't apply if it was originally 3× anyway. Just keep the gears, then you have a perfectly good narrow-gap rear but still also the low front gears in case you should ever need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense if it makes sense for you. As you use the same rear cassette/freehweel, you'll need to stick to using same 6-speed chains as before.

I assume your current setup has a triple front chainring. If there are no issues with exclusively using the middle front chainring with all 6 rear cogs, neither from the drivetrain (no rub/noise/ chain jumping etc) nor from the rider, then I'd say the triple can be replaced with a single chainring put in the middle position.

You should look out for the chainstay-teeth clearance; the middle ring sits closer to the frame than the biggest ring, and as so it has to be relatively smaller to clear the frame. Unless you plan to go with something crazy however (48 teeth might be the case), I am sure you'll be fine.

6-speed chains are a bit wider than 9/10/11 speed ones, which narrow-wide chainrings are designed around. Also, your derailleur won't have a clutch to maintain chain tension. This means that chain retention will be less than it could be, but for the hybrid bicycle usage cases, I do not think you will notice that.